# Desktop and laptop network speed difference

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

I have desktop with Win 10 connected to 1 Gbps router via Ethernet, the link is full 1 Gbps (in `ncpa.cpl`).
Also I have old laptop (Lenovo Y500) with the same networking configuration (NICs surely differ, but both are 1 Gbps Ethernet).

I am living in Warsaw, Poland. I am observing that download from my two servers (Amsterdam and Chicago) on desktop are giving more than 20 MB/s (FTPS), up to 30 MB/s.
The link is 600 Mbit download and 30 Mbit upload nominal (checked on `speedtest.net`). Both NICs are set for default settings.

The same application (Total Commander) with the same download on laptop is giving maximally 2 MB/s for Amsterdam and 512 kB/s for Chicago. Switching to Wi-Fi (2.4 GHz) does not help.

Why there is so much difference in the transfer? Ubuntu image download is also slow. But networking speed tests give max...

Can I make sth with laptop to achieve higher speed?

Comment: Check the [Lenovo driver](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/) for your exact model. Especially for network and wifi.

Comment: @harrymc Both NICs have newest drivers.

Comment: Which operating system(s)?

Comment: Have you tried an HTTP or HTTPS download from the same sites? Have you tried tests which don't touch storage, such as iperf3 between the two computers?

Comment: Desktop & laptop = Win 10 x64 Pro. Remote = both Linux vsftpd up-to-date. HTTP is slow for laptop, not for desktop. All computers have SSD drives. Home computers see each other at ~115 MB/s.

Comment: If you have installed the old Lenovo drivers for the ethernet & wifi devices, delete the devices in the Device Manager along with their drivers and reboot for Windows to install its own drivers.

Comment: There are no newer or better drivers for this adapter.

Comment: @harrymc I've done that and on older=MS driver it is the same. I reinstalled newest driver and it is the same. Older=2.1.0.16, newer=2.1.0.21.

Comment: Long shot, but have you compared MTU's! Also, is it safe to assume both laptop and desktop are on same man, and have you used the same Ethernet  cable in both tests. (Its possible the WiFi is a red herring. I also wonder if there us an IP address conflict.

Comment: @davidgo MTUs are default and computers locally have max speed. I've made tests on Ethernet, not Wi-Fi. There is no IP address conflict.